# How to make DropDownListFor with input text inside

Tags: .net, input, textbox, dropdown, selectlistitem

what i want to do is to create a DropDownListFor with two options:

1: Enter value

2: Set null value

The option number 1 should be a TextBoxFor inside the dropdown, I have no idea how to do this.

.Net C#

Answer (score 0):

What I did is:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id='@String.Format("DropdownCriticalMin{0}", Model.ParametersLimits[listIndex].ID)' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       My Dropdown
          <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="'@String.Format("DropdownCriticalMin{0}", Model.ParametersLimits[listIndex].ID)'">
       <li>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ParametersLimits[listIndex].CriticalMin, new
                     {
                       @class = "form-control ",
                       id = String.Format("criticalMin{0}", Model.ParametersLimits[listIndex].ID),
                       onblur = "checkLimitLogic(this)",
                       data_val = "true",
                       data_val_range = String.Format(Errors.CriticalMinLogicError, Model.ParametersLimits[listIndex].Name)
                      })
       </li>
       <li><a onclick="setNull('@String.Format(" criticalMin{0}", Model.ParametersLimits[listIndex].ID)')">Ustaw puste</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

if you have any suggestions, I would be happy to see them :)